# Why is the default IPv6 address changed after installing Docker and how to avoid it

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using Ansible to install Docker on a Debian system. And I need to identify the `ansible_default_ipv6.address` in some tasks. After installing Docker the setup task returns a different "default" (the docker0 interface) instead of the "eth0" or "ens18" or whatever. So it isn't really a problem with Docker but with changes on the network interfaces. Maybe this happens to, if you configure OpenVPN etc.

I don't understand, why the `ansible_default_ipv6.address` changed (maybe because "d" is earlier then "e"). I would expect that the "scope global" is more important then "scope global tentative" from docker0

But also - how could I avoid that behaviour? Is it best practice to define a per host variable about the interface or the IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, it IS because "d" is before "e":

In theory, Ansible selects [the device with the default gateway](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/cd4736d893a47c9ebd7796d8c9fec5180ca22488/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/network/linux.py#L67-L68) as the "default" interface. In practice, it's often just the interface that comes first in the alphabet.

So before installing docker, `eth0` is the default interface, but after installing docker there's a new `docker0` interface (which comes before `eth0` when sorted alphabetical), so Ansible now declares `docker0` as the "default" interface.

**Solution:** Do not use `ansible_default_ipv6` and use the interface specific facts instead (`ansible_eth0["ipv4"]...`)

Comment: the problem is, I have hosts with eth0 and ens18 etc. So I need to identify the e* interface. 

To avoid defining ens18 or eth0 etc. I made a fact like this:
´´´
    - set_fact:
        interface: "{{ ansible_interfaces | select('match', '^(e.*)[0-9]+') | list | sort | first}}"
    - set_fact:
        ipv6: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_'+interface]['ipv6'] | selectattr('scope', 'equalto', 'global') | list | first }}}"
```
Of course - if there are more then one e* interfaces (like internal and external) then this would be a problem again.

Comment: Funny part is that you see everywhere the ansible_default_ipv6 variable as an example which could be a problem.